# After I execute a certain function, attempting to read files always causes errors

Tags: c++, file-io

This probably has nothing to do with the problem, but here's the context: I have been following a tutorial on OpenGL and decided to try creating my own bone system before looking up a potentially better implementation.
Here's the problem: I have created a simple text-based format for my skeleton file. I also load an OBJ file, two GLSL shaders, and a texture in PNG format. (In case it matters, I load the texture using STB Image from [nothings.org](http://nothings.org/)). All of my file loading has been successful before. Loading the skeleton file is successful, but **after I load the skeleton file, all subsequent attempts to load files fail**, producing various errors, depending on the placement of the function call. In the position I prefer to have it, it produces a SIGABRT.

Here is my code to initialize a skeleton, plus includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include "model_stuff.hpp"
#include "skeleton_stuff.hpp"


void Skeleton::init(const char *sklfile) {
  std::ifstream in(sklfile, std::ios::in);
  if (!in) { std::cerr << "Cannot open " << sklfile << std::endl; exit(1); }

  std::string line;
  getline(in, line);
  if(line.substr(0,2) == "i ") {
    std::istringstream s(line.substr(2));
    s >> this->numBinds;
    this->boneBinds = new BoneBind[numBinds];
  } else {
    std::cerr << "Error: Missing information line for " << sklfile << std::endl; exit(1);
  }
  while (getline(in, line)) {
    if(line.substr(0,2) == "b ") {
      std::istringstream s(line.substr(2));
      std::string name;
      s >> name;
      glm::vec4 pos;
      s >> pos.x; s >> pos.y; s >> pos.z; pos.w = 1.0f;
    } else if(line.substr(0,2) == "v ") {
      std::istringstream s(line.substr(2));
      int v;
      s >> v;
      std::vector<Bone*> bones;
      while(!s.eof()) {
        std::string str;
        s >> str;
        bones.push_back(this->boneNamed(str));
      }
      float boneweight = 1.0f;
      if(bones.size() > 0) {
        boneweight = 0.5f;
      }
      boneBinds[v].boneweight = bones.size();
      boneBinds[v].childbone = bones[0];
      if(boneweight != 1.0f) {
        boneBinds[v].superbone = bones[1];
      } else {
        boneBinds[v].superbone = bones[0];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output from gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pitzik4/Dropbox/Pitzik4/cppWorkspaces/glTestWorkspace/Triangle2/bin/model 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
*** glibc detected *** /home/pitzik4/Dropbox/Pitzik4/cppWorkspaces/glTestWorkspace/Triangle2/bin/model: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000000d630c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7e626)[0x7ffff6b7a626]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(_mesa_symbol_table_dtor+0x55)[0x7ffff4537bb5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so(_ZN17glsl_symbol_tableD1Ev+0xd)[0x7ffff41024dd]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so(_Z22cross_validate_globalsP17gl_shader_programPP9gl_shaderjb+0x116)[0x7ffff4112306]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so(_Z12link_shadersP10gl_contextP17gl_shader_program+0x260)[0x7ffff4113e40]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(_mesa_glsl_link_shader+0xfb)[0x7ffff459e21b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(_mesa_get_fixed_func_fragment_program+0xa59)[0x7ffff4592c39]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(_mesa_update_state_locked+0x872)[0x7ffff44978e2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(_mesa_update_state+0x11)[0x7ffff4497d51]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(+0xcfc48)[0x7ffff44a9c48]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(_mesa_TexImage2D+0x54)[0x7ffff44aa364]
/home/pitzik4/Dropbox/Pitzik4/cppWorkspaces/glTestWorkspace/Triangle2/bin/model[0x418b1d]
/home/pitzik4/Dropbox/Pitzik4/cppWorkspaces/glTestWorkspace/Triangle2/bin/model[0x419a28]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffff6b1d76d]
/home/pitzik4/Dropbox/Pitzik4/cppWorkspaces/glTestWorkspace/Triangle2/bin/model[0x403339]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00423000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 4456901                            /home/pitzik4/Dropbox/Pitzik4/cppWorkspaces/glTestWorkspace/Triangle2/bin/model
00622000-00623000 r--p 00022000 08:05 4456901                            /home/pitzik4/Dropbox/Pitzik4/cppWorkspaces/glTestWorkspace/Triangle2/bin/model
00623000-00624000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 4456901                            /home/pitzik4/Dropbox/Pitzik4/cppWorkspaces/glTestWorkspace/Triangle2/bin/model
00624000-00d7e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff2efb000-7ffff3841000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff3841000-7ffff3857000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1576592                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7ffff3857000-7ffff3a56000 ---p 00016000 08:05 1576592                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7ffff3a56000-7ffff3a57000 r--p 00015000 08:05 1576592                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7ffff3a57000-7ffff3a58000 rw-p 00016000 08:05 1576592                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7ffff3a58000-7ffff3a60000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5120173                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.0
7ffff3a60000-7ffff3c5f000 ---p 00008000 08:05 5120173                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.0
7ffff3c5f000-7ffff3c60000 r--p 00007000 08:05 5120173                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.0
7ffff3c60000-7ffff3c61000 rw-p 00008000 08:05 5120173                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.0
7ffff3c61000-7ffff3c7d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119862                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7ffff3c7d000-7ffff3e7c000 ---p 0001c000 08:05 5119862                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7ffff3e7c000-7ffff3e7d000 r--p 0001b000 08:05 5119862                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7ffff3e7d000-7ffff3e7e000 rw-p 0001c000 08:05 5119862                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7ffff3e7e000-7ffff3ea5000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1576499                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
7ffff3ea5000-7ffff40a5000 ---p 00027000 08:05 1576499                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
7ffff40a5000-7ffff40a7000 r--p 00027000 08:05 1576499                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
7ffff40a7000-7ffff40a8000 rw-p 00029000 08:05 1576499                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
7ffff40a8000-7ffff41ce000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1569                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
7ffff41ce000-7ffff43cd000 ---p 00126000 08:05 1569                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
7ffff43cd000-7ffff43d6000 r--p 00125000 08:05 1569                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
7ffff43d6000-7ffff43d9000 rw-p 0012e000 08:05 1569                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
7ffff43d9000-7ffff43da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff43da000-7ffff4618000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1570                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
7ffff4618000-7ffff4818000 ---p 0023e000 08:05 1570                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
7ffff4818000-7ffff4822000 r--p 0023e000 08:05 1570                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
7ffff4822000-7ffff4825000 rw-p 00248000 08:05 1570                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
7ffff4825000-7ffff483b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff483b000-7ffff4909000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1334                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
7ffff4909000-7ffff4b09000 ---p 000ce000 08:05 1334                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
7ffff4b09000-7ffff4b0c000 r--p 000ce000 08:05 1334                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
7ffff4b0c000-7ffff4b10000 rw-p 000d1000 08:05 1334                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
7ffff4b10000-7ffff4b17000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1576567                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7ffff4b17000-7ffff4d16000 ---p 00007000 08:05 1576567                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7ffff4d16000-7ffff4d17000 r--p 00006000 08:05 1576567                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7ffff4d17000-7ffff4d18000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 1576567                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7ffff4d18000-7ffff4d1d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119694                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7ffff4d1d000-7ffff4f1c000 ---p 00005000 08:05 5119694                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7ffff4f1c000-7ffff4f1d000 r--p 00004000 08:05 5119694                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7ffff4f1d000-7ffff4f1e000 rw-p 00005000 08:05 5119694                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7ffff4f1e000-7ffff4f20000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119681                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ffff4f20000-7ffff511f000 ---p 00002000 08:05 5119681                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ffff511f000-7ffff5120000 r--p 00001000 08:05 5119681                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ffff5120000-7ffff5121000 rw-p 00002000 08:05 5119681                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ffff5121000-7ffff5123000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1576494                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
7ffff5123000-7ffff5323000 ---p 00002000 08:05 1576494                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
7ffff5323000-7ffff5324000 r--p 00002000 08:05 1576494                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
7ffff5324000-7ffff5325000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 1576494                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
7ffff5325000-7ffff532f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119860                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7ffff532f000-7ffff552e000 ---p 0000a000 08:05 5119860                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7ffff552e000-7ffff552f000 r--p 00009000 08:05 5119860                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7ffff552f000-7ffff5530000 rw-p 0000a000 08:05 5119860                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7ffff5530000-7ffff5534000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119726                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7ffff5534000-7ffff5733000 ---p 00004000 08:05 5119726                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7ffff5733000-7ffff5734000 r--p 00003000 08:05 5119726                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7ffff5734000-7ffff5735000 rw-p 00004000 08:05 5119726                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7ffff5735000-7ffff5752000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5120366                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ffff5752000-7ffff5951000 ---p 0001d000 08:05 5120366                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ffff5951000-7ffff5952000 r--p 0001c000 08:05 5120366                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ffff5952000-7ffff5953000 rw-p 0001d000 08:05 5120366                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ffff5953000-7ffff5968000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5120350                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7ffff5968000-7ffff5b67000 ---p 00015000 08:05 5120350                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7ffff5b67000-7ffff5b69000 r--p 00014000 08:05 5120350                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7ffff5b69000-7ffff5b6a000 rw-p 00016000 08:05 5120350                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7ffff5b6a000-7ffff5b6b000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119673                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7ffff5b6b000-7ffff5d6a000 ---p 00001000 08:05 5119673                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7ffff5d6a000-7ffff5d6b000 r--p 00000000 08:05 5119673                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7ffff5d6b000-7ffff5d6c000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 5119673                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7ffff5d6c000-7ffff5d71000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119698                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7ffff5d71000-7ffff5f70000 ---p 00005000 08:05 5119698                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7ffff5f70000-7ffff5f71000 r--p 00004000 08:05 5119698                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7ffff5f71000-7ffff5f72000 rw-p 00005000 08:05 5119698                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7ffff5f72000-7ffff5f74000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119690                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7ffff5f74000-7ffff6173000 ---p 00002000 08:05 5119690                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7ffff6173000-7ffff6174000 r--p 00001000 08:05 5119690                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7ffff6174000-7ffff6175000 rw-p 00002000 08:05 5119690                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7ffff6175000-7ffff6185000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119696                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ffff6185000-7ffff6384000 ---p 00010000 08:05 5119696                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ffff6384000-7ffff6385000 r--p 0000f000 08:05 5119696                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ffff6385000-7ffff6386000 rw-p 00010000 08:05 5119696                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ffff6386000-7ffff63a7000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5126526                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7ffff63a7000-7ffff65a6000 ---p 00021000 08:05 5126526                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7ffff65a6000-7ffff65a9000 r--p 00020000 08:05 5126526                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7ffff65a9000-7ffff65aa000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 5126526                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7ffff65aa000-7ffff65ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff65ab000-7ffff66da000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119677                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ffff66da000-7ffff68da000 ---p 0012f000 08:05 5119677                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ffff68da000-7ffff68db000 r--p 0012f000 08:05 5119677                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ffff68db000-7ffff68df000 rw-p 00130000 08:05 5119677                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ffff68df000-7ffff68f7000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1576561                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7ffff68f7000-7ffff6af6000 ---p 00018000 08:05 1576561                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7ffff6af6000-7ffff6af7000 r--p 00017000 08:05 1576561                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7ffff6af7000-7ffff6af8000 rw-p 00018000 08:05 1576561                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7ffff6af8000-7ffff6afc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff6afc000-7ffff6caf000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1576481                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff6caf000-7ffff6eae000 ---p 001b3000 08:05 1576481                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff6eae000-7ffff6eb2000 r--p 001b2000 08:05 1576481                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff6eb2000-7ffff6eb4000 rw-p 001b6000 08:05 1576481                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff6eb4000-7ffff6eb9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff6eb9000-7ffff6ece000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1576502                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff6ece000-7ffff70cd000 ---p 00015000 08:05 1576502                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff70cd000-7ffff70ce000 r--p 00014000 08:05 1576502                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff70ce000-7ffff70cf000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 1576502                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff70cf000-7ffff71c8000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1576513                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff71c8000-7ffff73c7000 ---p 000f9000 08:05 1576513                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff73c7000-7ffff73c8000 r--p 000f8000 08:05 1576513                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff73c8000-7ffff73c9000 rw-p 000f9000 08:05 1576513                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff73c9000-7ffff74ab000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5120266                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff74ab000-7ffff76aa000 ---p 000e2000 08:05 5120266                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff76aa000-7ffff76b2000 r--p 000e1000 08:05 5120266                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff76b2000-7ffff76b4000 rw-p 000e9000 08:05 5120266                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff76b4000-7ffff76c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff76c9000-7ffff7726000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2898                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
7ffff7726000-7ffff7925000 ---p 0005d000 08:05 2898                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
7ffff7925000-7ffff7927000 r--p 0005c000 08:05 2898                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
7ffff7927000-7ffff7928000 rw-p 0005e000 08:05 2898                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
7ffff7928000-7ffff7929000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7929000-7ffff798a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 5119616                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.6.0
7ffff798a000-7ffff7b89000 ---p 00061000 08:05 5119616                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.6.0
7ffff7b89000-7ffff7b8f000 r--p 00060000 08:05 5119616                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.6.0
7ffff7b8f000-7ffff7b90000 rw-p 00066000 08:05 5119616                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.6.0
7ffff7b90000-7ffff7b94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6b32445 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6b32445 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6b35bab in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff6b6fe2e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff6b7a626 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff4537bb5 in _mesa_symbol_table_dtor ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
#5  0x00007ffff41024dd in glsl_symbol_table::~glsl_symbol_table() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
#6  0x00007ffff4112306 in cross_validate_globals(gl_shader_program*, gl_shader**, unsigned int, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
#7  0x00007ffff4113e40 in link_shaders(gl_context*, gl_shader_program*) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
#8  0x00007ffff459e21b in _mesa_glsl_link_shader ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
#9  0x00007ffff4592c39 in _mesa_get_fixed_func_fragment_program ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
#10 0x00007ffff44978e2 in _mesa_update_state_locked ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
#11 0x00007ffff4497d51 in _mesa_update_state ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
#12 0x00007ffff44a9c48 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
#13 0x00007ffff44aa364 in _mesa_TexImage2D ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
#14 0x0000000000418b1d in initResources () at src/model.cpp:126
#15 0x0000000000419a28 in main (argc=1, args=0x7fffffffe7e8)
    at src/model.cpp:350
```

I am using make to compile with g++ -g. I'm running 64-bit Linux Mint.

That's all of the potentially useful information I could think of. If I did not supply enough information here to find a solution to this problem, just add a comment and I'll put in an edit with the info.

So... What can I do to fix this problem? I've been intermittently Googling it and trying to fix it for hours now, to no avail.

Comment: It looks like memory corruption to me. As a quick test, you can comment out everything related to bones/boneBinds and call the function reading the same file, will it fail? As a note, this code is unsafe since it relies heavily on skeleton file being correct - you are indexing elements of bonBinds array based on number v read from file, it may work on one skeletone file and not on the other - think about safer structure?

Comment: I tried that, all files loaded successfully this time! There was, of course, a segmentation fault later on, but that is to be expected. And about relying on the skeleton file being properly formatted, I know, I'm just trying something out here, not trying to make a game or anything.

Comment: I would add `if (v < 0 || v >= numBinds) cerr << "Bad stuff...  v=" << v << endl;` somewhere before your stuff things into `boneBinds[v]`

Comment: Probably, you are writing past the allocated size of boneBinds, which causes memory corruption. However, you only note it later on when you try to read another files, but the reason for crush is either in BoneBind constructor, or going past allocated size of bonesBinds

Comment: Mats: I see now! Since the SKL file was generated from an MTL file and an OBJ file, the vertex definitons are one-based, while c++ arrays are zero-based! Thanks for that suggestion. I added a v--; and it has moved on to new errors, hopefully ones I can solve myself this time.

Comment: `I found an answer, but the website won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours. Here is what I would put in the answer:` No! Bad! Wait the 8 hours please, rather than just ignoring the rule and doing the backwards step of writing an answer into the question.